# Can't boot into windows 10

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, efi, boot-partition

I can't boot into windows 10. The partitions on my ssd are:

- ESP
- Reserved Partition (I assume for windows 10)
- Windows 10
- Windows 10
- Recovery

I can't select which Windows 10 OS to boot into. I thought that ESP would recognize that I have two copies of Windows and let me select which to boot into. (When I installed the second Windows 10, I just copied the original Windows 10 partition to free space after it.) I plan on Multibooting with Ubuntu as soon as I get this working. Do you think if I installed Ubuntu right now, it would see both copies of Windows 10 or just one?

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you just want to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu? Or do you actually want 2 copies of Windows? When you say you can't boot in win 10, do you mean you can't boot into Windows at all, or just that you can't access the second copy?

Comment: Im going to college in a month and id prefer a second copy of the OS installed (windows 10) so i can keep college things separate from free time things. Along with both windows 10 partitions i would also like to have ubuntu installed as well. I can boot into windows 10 but im not POSITIVE which version. I do suspect it is the original as the system drive says C still and that is what it was set at.

Comment: I don't think it will work the way you did it. Windows doesn't like to be copied... I would delete the second Windows 10 partition. Then boot off of a Windows 10 install DVD or USB stick and install it manually to the unallocated space.

Comment: I dont have a windows 10 install disk. I also dont have internet to download it. Im using data from my phone for this. Do you know of any ways to copy windows and boot it?

Comment: I dont know if this makes a difference but i have an ESP on my ssd

Comment: you have to add a boot record for 2nd windows install. you can do it manually or you can use a tool like EasyBCD .